# Get index model in function with Ember.js rc1

Tags: ember-data

I started to learning Ember.JS for 1 week and I don't understand a part of them : get the model of the index controller when I use an action (like a button click).

There is a part of my code :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   <button class="btn btn-danger" {{action "addPost"}}> test</button>
</script>
```

There is my IndexController :

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    addPost: function() {
        var po = this.controllerFor('index').get('model');
        console.log(po);
            po.createRecord({
               title: "YOLO",
               description: "Simply",
               date: "2013-03-01"
            });
    }
});
```

My model :

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('date')
});
```

So when I log without `.get('model')`, I've got a Class return and when I use it I've got the same. So why ? Is it normal ? And both case, I've got an error who says "[Object object] has no method createRecord".

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new record, you only need to invoke the `createRecord` method of the model class itself.

Try this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  addPost: function() {
    var po = App.Post.createRecord({
      title: "YOLO",
      description: "Simply",
      date: "2013-03-01"
    });
  }
});
```